# Deploying WAR File in Tomcat (paths)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web, filepath

I am deploying a WAR file in Tomcat for a webapp (my first time doing this) that I've developed.
The problem comes when I deploy the app and the resources can't be found.

I am saving the files (for example a CSV file) in this foulder of the project:

`"src/main/resources/diseases.csv"`

And when I deploy the project in tomcat, tomcat give me this error:

```
"org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.16/bin/src/main/resources/conenfermedad.csv;"
```

This is the line of the code where I am having the error:

```
String dataPred = thalg.randtrp("src/main/resources/conenfermedad.csv",             
                "src/main/resources/outWekaEnfermedad.arff");
```

**EDIT**:
I have been trying differents solutions but I have the same problem because if I use InputStream how can I get the path to use a dataFrameReader (this only use path as String)?

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(In);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        //InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(In);

        final DataFrameReader dataFrameReader = sparkSession.read().option("header", true);
        final Dataset<Row> trainingData = dataFrameReader.csv(In).toDF("IDPatient", "ECG_EKG", "Temp",
                "SPO2Min", "SPO2Max", "BPMmin", "BPMmax", "BPMavg", "SYS", "DIA", "EDAmin", "EDAmax", "EDAavg", "Disease");
        // con "*.csv" para que lea todo el directorio
```

What should am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSV-file is included in your WAR-file. Since a WAR-file is technically just a ZIP-file you can use any ZIP-program to check this.

If you are using Maven you need to explicitly include it:

```
<build>
...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>diseases.csv</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
...
</build>
```

`Filtering` can be set to false (or left out) if you don't need any replacement of placeholders. In the `include` tag you can also use [wildcards](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html).

And then you can use the csv file like this:

```
new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/diseases.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
```

Comment: Using getResourceAsStream is exactly what is suggested by answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar A duplicate question doesn't deserve a duplicate answer,

Comment: @Pino Since OP already uses getResourceAsStream in his edit something else is wrong and my guess is that the file is not included in the WAR.

Comment: Yes, now I have seen the edit, but it's not clear how OP is using the result of getResourceAsStream().  Perhaps he should read better the examples already available in that post.